# firebase text detection after I have updated my Xcode 11 and iOS 13 not working

Tags: swift, firebase, swift5, firebase-mlkit

Hello everyone I have updated my Xcode to 11 and my iPhone to iOS 13 . I am using firebase ml text detection with live camera to detect the text , and updated firebase libraries . the problem is this code now not working and show to me strange error show in the picture [error image](https://ibb.co/jfT821y) 
before update this error was found I have tried many ways  to solve this problem there is no hope. I hope someone help me .

```
//MARK:- CAMERA SETUP VIEW //=======================================================

    func cameraSetUp(){
        //MARK INPUT
        captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
        guard  let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else {return}
        guard  let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput.init(device: captureDevice) else {return}
        captureSession.addInput(input)
        captureSession.startRunning()
        //MARK OUTPUT
        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        cameraview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        previewLayer.frame = cameraview.layer.bounds
        let dataoutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "VideoQueue")
        dataoutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
        captureSession.addOutput(dataoutput)

    }

//MARK:- CAMERA captureOutput //=======================================================
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

         self.cameraOperation (buffer : sampleBuffer)

    }

//MARK:- CAMERA Operation //=======================================================
    func cameraOperation (buffer : CMSampleBuffer){
       let textRecognizer = vision.onDeviceTextRecognizer()
       Using_back_facing_camera (metadata : metadata)
      let image = VisionImage(buffer: buffer )
          image.metadata = metadata
        // Using back-facing camera

        self.detectText (image : image, textRecognizer: textRecognizer)
    }


    func Using_back_facing_camera (metadata :VisionImageMetadata){
        // Using back-facing camera
            let devicePosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position = .back
            let deviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
            switch deviceOrientation {
            case .portrait:
                metadata.orientation = devicePosition == .front ? .leftTop : .rightTop
            case .landscapeLeft:
                metadata.orientation = devicePosition == .front ? .bottomLeft : .topLeft
            case .portraitUpsideDown:
                metadata.orientation = devicePosition == .front ? .rightBottom : .leftBottom
            case .landscapeRight:
                metadata.orientation = devicePosition == .front ? .topRight : .bottomRight
            case .faceDown, .faceUp, .unknown:
                metadata.orientation = .leftTop
            }
    }

    //MARK:- THIS FUNC RESPONSABLE FOR DETECT THE TEXT
    func detectText (image : VisionImage , textRecognizer: VisionTextRecognizer) {
//        let imageTest = VisionImage(image: UIImage(named:"test1")!)
            textRecognizer.process(image) { [weak self ] result, error in

                       guard let self = self else {return}
                       guard error == nil else {return}
                       guard  let result = result else {return}
                       if self.passToAnotherPage == true {
                        print(result.text)
                           self.KSSView.text = result.text
                           self.resultText = result.text
                           self.filterCamera(resultText : self.resultText)
                       } else {
                           self.resultText = ""
                       }

                   }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error highlighted in the error image is harmless. There are multiple other errors in the log that may indicate issue(s) in the app's code.

Please try out the text recognition examples in the ML Kit's QuickStart mlvision sample apps available at:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios.git

It works fine on iOS 13.1 with Xcode 11.0.

Comment: I saw the Quickstart  code it's like my code I am using now